# Gear shift rubber cover liquified, post cure possible?

Tags: shifter

I recently got my bike out of storage and the rubber cover on the right gear shifter is liquified.
The rubber is basically a sticky oily paste now.
It's just the right gear shifter cover, even the rubber handlebar cover next to it is fine.

What kind of rubber are the gear shifter covers usually made of and can I post cure it with some chemical or heat? 
Or do I need to exchange it?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Probably it got some sort of oil or solvent on it.

Comment: What shifter is it? Some gripshift/revoshifts have had replacement rubber available.

Answer (score 2):

Once the rubber has gone gummy, its game-over for that part.  You have two real options.

1. Cheap answer - Cover the gummy part
   I've put cheap heatshrink tube over some bar grips that were deteriorating.  That was ~5 years ago and they're still working fine on my MTB.   Since its not a round part, you might get away with a layer of tape.
   Downside is that the goop will soak through most tapes, and plastic tapes will be harsh on your hands.
2. Outright replacement of the hoods. 
   Find your shifter's model number and start searching.  I see plenty on ebay, selling for 10 pounds to 20 dollars.  Expect to pay more for brand-originals, but they're more likely to fit.

[image: From some random ebay listing]

Doing nothing is not really an option - they'll only ever get worse, sticking to you and your skin and gloves.

You might choose to cut the old hoods off, and ride bare, but that will expose some of the internal gubbins to the elements and to your sweat.  Also this would give sharpish edges that will chafe and irritate your hands.

**I'd suggest you tape them temporarily, and start searching for new replacement hood covers.**

Comment: Maybe consider using self vulcanising tape? Its soft on the hands and won't come undone once applied

Comment: @Maarten-Monicaforpresident possibly workable, but realistically the hoods are shot and need replacing.  Anything else is just a temporary holding fix.